# Performance Issue: .NET HttpClient Response is slow

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

**Problem:**

I am using .NET Class `HttpClient` to make Requests to the endpoint URL.

**My Code:**

```
using (HttpClient apiClient1 = new HttpClient())
{
    apiClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
}
```

**Problem Identified:**

If I use `using` block, I'm opening multiple connections, leads to `socketExceptions`.

**Changed My Above Code to:**

```
public class RequestController: ApiController
{
    private static HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient();

    [HttpPost]
    public  dynamic GetWebApiData([FromBody] ParamData params)
    {
           var resultContent = apiClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result.Content;
           return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(resultContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
}
```

Result of the above code after making `HttpClient` as `static` is as follows:

1. Only one Connection is established.
2. For Each request, I'm looking for the 200 milliseconds reduction in
       Response Time.

**What I Need:**

I want to make conurrent calls atleast 50 calls to the end point with High-Speed response.

Kindly help me with this scenario.

Comment: You need to read up and understand the fundamentals of async/await. If you do, your question will be answered.

Comment: Also, how are you making the concurrent calls?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'm calling through internal WebApi Method "GetWebAPidata()", which then initiates HttpClient

Comment: @IanKemp, My question will not be answered, unless and until we could apply best approach to this kind of generic scenario, where we need to make multiple EndPoint Requests with less time. I'm sorting out where the problem went wrong. That's why I asked the question in this forum, where someone help me to get rid off. It's just discussion. Sorry If I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, but that method only makes *one* request. How are you calling it 50 times concurrently? That code is just as important.

Answer (score 8):

Use the async API and stop calling `.Result` blocking calls.

```
public class RequestController: ApiController {
    private static HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetWebApiData([FromBody] ParamData data) {
        var response = await apiClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
        var resultContent = response.Content;
        var model = await resultContent.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: This reduces the time and now it is taking 300 - 400 ms to get the result. Is it the right time consumption as I verified it by pinging the IP Address of the server through ping {IPAddress}, it is taking 245 milliseconds 1 roundtrip. Is it feasible to wait for this 300 - 400ms delay? Also, how the ".Result" will block the calls? Could you explain?

Comment: A ping would obviously be faster as no work is being done. The time mentioned is reasonable but that is a matter of preference.

Comment: @Vikash Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The default SSL connection idle timeout of HttpClient are 2 mins. So, after that you have to re handshake with the server. This maybe the root cause.

You could follow this article(https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core) to extend the timeout. But the testing result from my side, I could only extend to 5 mins. After that, the connection will be closed.